# How to use order by clause in XQUERY subsequence?

Tags: xquery

I have a table named TBTASK structure is as follows

```
PRIID CHARACTER(15) NOT NULL,
BID CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL,
REF CHARACTER(15) NOT NULL,
TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP,
XMLREC XML NOT NULL
```

XML stored in DB XMLREC column is as follows

```
<Root><Code>6</Code><Id>4</Id><Number>999</Number></Root>
<Root><Code>6</Code><Id>4</Id><Number>1001</Number></Root>
<Root><Code>6</Code><Id>4</Id><Number>1002</Number></Root>
<Root><Code>6</Code><Id>4</Id><Number>998</Number></Root>
```

Im using below XQUERY for geeting the data:

```
XQUERY
let $str:= subsequence((db2-fn:sqlquery( 'SELECT XMLREC FROM LIS.TBTASK WHERE BID=1') 
    /Root[Code='6']),1,5)    
order by $str/Root/Number
return ($str)
```

but Im not getting the result in sorted order as per NUMBER column(order by is applied on NUMBER.

Could you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for $str in (db2-fn:sqlquery( 'SELECT XMLREC FROM LIS.TBTASK WHERE BID=1')/Root[Code='6']),1,5)    
order by xs:int($str/Number)
return ($str)
```

Note, that you need at least one for statement for order by to be useful. Also, your path ($str/Root/Number) was wrong as $str is already at the Root-Node. Additionally I assumed that you want to sort this in a numerical way and not as strings, so I added an explicit type cast to make it work.